# I need help using a dropdown menu to $_GET from a MySQL table using LIKE from a group of tags

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, get

So I have a table of items with multiple categories attached to them. I keep running into problems. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    <form class="forms" action="form.php" method="get">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Sort by Category</legend>
    <select name="tags">
    <option value="business" title="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="environmental" title="Environmental">Environmental</option>
    <option value="hospitality" title="Hospitality">Hospitality</option>
    </select><input type="submit" class="inputButton" value="Select Category" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    <?php
    $tags = $_GET['tags'];


    $connection = mysql_connect($local,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().' : '.mysql_error().'<br />');
    mysql_select_db($db);
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM awards WHERE active=1 ORDER BY name';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        if ($tags == 'business')
        {
            $where = "SELECT * FROM awards WHERE active=1 AND
tags LIKE '%business%' ORDER BY name";
}
    else if ($tags == 'environmental')
    {
        $where = "SELECT * FROM awards WHERE active=1 AND 
tags LIKE '%environmental%' ORDER BY name";
}
    else if ($tags == 'hospitality')
    {
        $where = "SELECT * FROM awards WHERE active=1 AND 
tags LIKE '%hospitality%' ORDER BY name";
    }
        else
        {
            $where = 'SELECT * FROM awards WHERE active=1 ORDER BY name';
            $title = 'Awards in Alphabetical Order';
        }
    }
    include 'conn.php';
    $connection = mysql_connect($local,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().' : '.mysql_error().'<br />');
    mysql_select_db($db);
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM awards $where';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
```

Afterwards, echo, etc., which I'm having no problem with. I just can't seem to get it to pull only the records I want it to. Am I going about this the wrong way? My row "tags" in my table has multiple comma-delimited values. So, if someone selects 'business', it should not pull any records that don't have 'business' as one of the tags. Should I have my "tags" as separate rows instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $tags = $_GET['tags'];

if ($tags == 'business' || $tags == 'environmental' || $tags == 'hospitality')
{
            $where = "SELECT * FROM awards WHERE active=1 AND
tags LIKE '%$tags%' ORDER BY name";
}
else
{
     $where = 'SELECT * FROM awards WHERE active=1 ORDER BY name';
            $title = 'Awards in Alphabetical Order';
}

include 'conn.php';
$connection = mysql_connect($local,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().' : '.mysql_error().'<br />');
mysql_select_db($db);
$result = mysql_query($where);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //echo here whatever u want from the rows fetched with matching tags
}
```

and you should start using PHP PDO for database access as the method being used here is getting depreciated soon..

[PDO Manual Link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I had to in order to get $row to work properly. Is it not necessary?

Comment: there seems to multiple problems in that code, for instance why do u have a `while` loop with `$row` value never used within the loop?

i have yupdated the code to what i think it should be. Let me know if i interpreted ur question wrongly